# how to modify an array value with given index?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I want to modify an array cell, which I can do when I know the cell as a number. However here my cell position is given by `$i`.

```
pomme[`${i}`]=""
```

I tried without the `` and it doesn't work either?

How am I suppose to do it?

Comment: `pomme[$i]=""` should work fine..

Comment: Don't get print the array content like this: `echo $pomme[$i]`, instead use `echo ${pomme[$i]}`. I guess that's why you think the value isn't updated.

Comment: `unset pomme[$i]` if you are simply clearing, otherwise `pomme[$i]=("")` If you are having issue, check the value of your `$i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the quotes. Just use `${i}`, or even `$i`:

```
pomme[${i}]=""
```

Or

```
pomme[$i]=""
```

Comment: In bash, you don't need the `$` either for **indexed** arrays, `a[i]` will do (treated like `((...))` )